# Invalid output with fscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

The language I am using is C
I am trying to scan data from a file, and the code segment is like:

```
char lsm;
long unsigned int address;
int objsize;
while(fscanf(mem_trace,"%c %lx,%d\n",&lsm,&address,&objsize)!=EOF){
    printf("%c %lx %d\n",lsm,address,objsize);
}
```

The file which I read from has the first line as follows:

```
 S 00600aa0,1
I  004005b6,5
I  004005bb,5
I  004005c0,5
 S 7ff000398,8
```

The results that show in stdout is:

```
  8048350 134524916
S 600aa0 1
I 4005b6 5
I 4005bb 5
I 4005c0 5
S 7ff000398,8
```

Obviously, the results had an extra line which comes nowhere.Is there anybody know how this could happen?
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on the data you supply:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char lsm[2];
    long unsigned int address;
    int objsize;
    while (scanf("%1s %lx,%d\n", lsm, &address, &objsize) == 3)
        printf("%s %9lx %d\n", lsm, address, objsize);
    return 0;
}
```

There are multiple changes.  The simplest and least consequential is the change from `fscanf()` to `scanf()`; that's for my convenience.

One important change is the type of `lsm` from a single `char` to an array of two characters.  The format string then uses `%1s` reads one character (plus NUL `'\0'`) into the string, but it also (and this is crucial) skips leading blanks.

Another change is the use of `== 3` instead of `!= EOF` in the condition.  If something goes wrong, `scanf()` returns the number of successful matches.  Suppose that it managed to read a letter but what followed was not a hex number; it would return 1 (not EOF).  Further, it would return 1 on each iteration until it could find something that matched a hex number.  Always test for the number of values you expect.

The output format was tidied up with the `%9lx`.  I was testing on a 64-bit system, so the 9-digit hex converts fine.  One problem with `scanf()` is that if you get an overflow on a conversion, the behaviour is undefined.

Output:

```
S    600aa0 1
I    4005b6 5
I    4005bb 5
I    4005c0 5
S 7ff000398 8
```

#### Why did you get the results you got?

The first conversion read a space into `lsm`, but then failed to convert `S` into a hex number, so it was left behind for the next cycle.  So, you got the left-over garbage printed in the address and object size columns.  The second iteration read the `S` and was then in synchrony with the data until the last line.  The newline at the end of the format (like any other white space in the format string) eats white space, which is why the last line worked despite the leading blank.

Answer (score 1):

> A directive that is a conversion specification defines a set of
> matching input sequences, as described below for each specifier. A
> conversion specification is executed in the following steps:
>
> Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function)
> are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.
>
> An input item is read from the stream, unless the specification
> includes an n specifier.
>
> [...]

The first time you call fscanf, your %c reads the first blank space in the file.  Your white-space character reads zero or more characters of white-space, this time zero of them.  Your %lx fails to match the S character in the file, so fscanf returns.  You don't check the result.  Your variables contain values that they had from earlier operations.

The second time you call fscanf, your %c reads the first S character in the file.  From that point on, everything else succeeds too.

Added in editing, here is the simplest change to your format string to solve your problem:

```
" %c %lx,%d\n"
```

The space at the beginning will read zero or more characters of white-space and then %c will read the first non-white-space character in the file.

Here is another format string that will also solve your problem:

```
" %c %lx,%d"
```

The reason is that if you read and discard zero or more white-space characters twice in a row, the result is the same as doing it just once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that fsanf reads the first character [space] into `lsm` then fails to read `address` and `objsize` because the format shift doesn't match for the rest of the line.

Then it prints a space then whatever happened to be in `address` and `objsize` when it was declared

EDIT--

fscanf consumes the whitespaces after each call, if you call ftell you'll see

```
printf("%c %lx %d %d\n",lsm,address,objsize,ftell(mem_trace));
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be right. But it only happen in the very begining of the file. Because there are also a line beginning with a space in the rest of file, but the output seems ok

Comment: Well, in you post the output stops before that line

Comment: @shirley fscanf consumes the whitespaces after each call, if you call ftell you'll see